# HTML class not linking to internal CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img.cardoption {width=20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class='cardoption' src='http://s32.postimg.org/9vao2t9kl/scc_std.png'/>
</body>
</html>
```

In this simple piece of HTML, and accompanying CSS, I have an image with class name 'cardoption'. In the style tag in the head, I have attempted to set the width of this image to 20px.

However, for some reason the image is not resizing. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: `=` isn't valid CSS, use `:` instead. I'm voting to close this question since it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
img.cardoption {width:20px;}
```

Replace `=` with `:`

(`=` is used for HTML attributes and `:` is used for CSS)

Comment: Please flag to close this type of question instead of answering it.